# How to copy in ansible using copy module

Tags: ansible

I am trying to copy a file from my local to remote using copy module in Ansible, but I am getting some error.

I have used the copy module of Ansible and below is the code.

```
---
- name: Execute ZFS storage pool
  hosts: core1
  tasks:
  - name: copy zfs.exp file to core node in mode equivalent to 0644
    copy:
      src: zfs.exp
      dest: /tmp/zfs.exp
      mode: u=rw,g=r,o=r
```

The expected output should be able to copy, but I am getting below error.

> fatal: [core1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "425615f087a0e3cbc4566de464797070558479ec", "msg": "Aborting, target uses
>   selinux but python bindings (libselinux-python) aren't installed!"}

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"target uses selinux but python bindings (libselinux-python) aren't installed!"*

A: Install `libselinux-python` on `core1`. The package depends on the system. For example [Centos](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libselinux-python-2.5-14.1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) or [Ubuntu LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python-selinux).